# Making divs clickable - Ember view for action on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am developing a Cordova application with help from Ember. I have many dynamic elements in my application. These are `Bootstrap` thumbnails that link to other routes when clicked.

I want to make these thumbnails `clickable`. If I use `Views`, I will have to write unique views for all the thumbnails.

I have heard about mixins. Can a general View be defined that will :

1. Pass a model
2. Render a template for a route with the model

In other words, since each view semantically performs the same action, I want to be able to do something similar to

```
{{#each}}
  {{#view App.AllView this}}
   .
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

in the template and in the view :

```
App.AllView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt, model){
      this.controllerFor('route').set('content', model);
      this.transitionTo('route');
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Following @givanse's answer, I made the following component

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/thumbnail-view">
  <div {{bind-attr class=class}}>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        {{name}}
      </div>
      <img {{bind-attr src=image }}>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

and used it in my template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="types">
  <div class="row">
    {{#each model}}
    {{thumbnail-view action="goToCategory" class="col-xs-12" param=this name=name image=image}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

with an `Ember` component :

```
Pioneer.ThumbnailViewComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function(){
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('param'));
  }
});
```

The action `goToCategory` is defined in my `ApplicationRoute`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Components, something like:

```
<script data-template-name="index">
  {{#each}}
    {{img-thumbnail imgId="id/path/name"}}
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script data-template-name="components/img-thumbnail">
  {{! whatever you need to make your thumbnail }}
</script>

App.ImgThumbnailComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  // handle events, classes, etc.
});
```

See:

http://emberjs.com/guides/components/

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html